# A General approach to cURL with ASPX pages - help needed

Tags: php, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, curl

This is a bit general sort of a concept, but How would you approach `cURLing` a website that is written in `ASPX`.

I mean I have fighting with this for three days now, and I don't get what I am expecting for from `cURL`.

Maybe it is the `VIEWSTATE,EVENTVALIDATION` thing?
I am reading the form's VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION and write them back for the next POST.  Is there any magic happening there?

Is there anything happening behind the scenes that I might be missing ?

I am using `F12 of Internet Explorer developer tools`, and I have to say it seems to do a much better job at showing web traffic than `FireBug` (sorry, I wish it had), and I am following all the calls and the `POST` values just by their order. But still, I only get this far.

Any ideas, suggestions, insights however practical - will be honestly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I write a lot of data scrapers in PHP + cURL and while dealing with ASPX pages can be a pain in the ass, there's no magic happening there. You just need to get values of all the hidden fields like __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION, __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT etc. then include them in your POST request. If you do a lot of scraping, you might consider writing your own curl wrapper class implementing some method of extracting those values.

As for FireBug, try LiveHttpHeaders extension for Firefox. Not only does it let you see what's POSTed, but resend a POST request with modified values as well.

Comment: Is it possible to have a seemingly "htm" file that is actually an aspx doing stuff for you ?